# How do i find friends in mcbe

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I do not know how to make friends in minecraft, can someone please help? I have already searched multiple ways through the internet, but it's just hard to find a friend :(

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where does it go wrong?

Comment: Is this actually a gaming question though?

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows, you could try finding people to play with using the Find-A-Group feature on Xbox.

[image]

You can bring it up by pressing <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and selecting <kbd>Xbox Looking for Group</kbd> in the widget menu (leftmost button at the top bar).

---

Everybody is different, so you may not find the perfect person or group on your first try. Just keep hopping between groups and talking to people, and you'll eventually find a group to play with.

You could join in what is already happening, and eventually suggest something new of your choice to play but **don't force others to do what you want**.

**Also remember about stranger danger, to stay safe and be nice to others... And try not to immediately reveal personal information**.